# makehuman visemes to shape keys for unity

Tags: unity, shape-keys, makehuman

I'm very new to blender so bare with me.

The idea is I am trying to get lip syncing to work with my unity game using facial shape keys made from blender.

I have imported a "makehuman" character (mhx2 format) to blender. I know I need Shape keys for a script in unity3d. I am struggling with trying to export shape keys from blender to unity (Exported character as fbx format from blender).

With makehuman import it comes with a whole bunch of visemes. I would be more than happy to export these as shape keys with my model. I have tried setting the viseme then going and manually adding a "New Shape From Mix" shape key. It comes in as 0 being what I want it to look like and 1 being too much. So I move the shape key min range to -1 and max to 0. This doesn't work because the shape key doesn't appear in unity.

**Is there a way to export the preset visemes with my character as shape keys?** Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are not enough details in your question, there are many things that can go wrong.

Two things to note:

1) When you import mhx2 into Blender, you must choose to override the default settings at the import menu at the bottom left:

**​Override Exported Data: Checked;**

**Import Human Type: Base, Offset, Face Shapes;**

Masking: Apply, Conservation Mask;

Rigging: Add Rig, Rig Type - Exported, Custom Shapes.

2) Make sure you export your model from Blender in a fbx file.

3) Import your fbx file into Unity. Before you drag it into the view/hierarchy, make sure that in Inspector you have the box ticked for importing face shapes - should be the default but just in case.

[This tutorial](http://crazyminnowstudio.com/posts/using-makehuman-characters-with-salsa-lipsync/) is for a plugin for lip sync in Unity, which uses blend shapes/face shapes. You may or may not need it but the first half of the tutorial is very useful for your case. If you follow it step by step, you should be able to get the blend shapes/face shapes into Unity successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a checkbox you need to check in Blender when you export so that the visemes show up in Unity. If you still need this answer, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate somewhat.... perhaps with an image.